# Writing C# and CIM Application

Tags: c#, authorize.net-cim

I know this isn't straight programming and debated posting this for a few days.  I am interesting in writing a utility to talk to network switches and gather statistics via CIM.  After several days of searching I can't find any decent examples to help get started.  I did find one project from Microsoft but it queries machines running Windows and requires Windows 8.  I have Windows 7.  Also, the few examples I've seen use the WMI which I think is for talking to other Windows systems.

Does anyone have any suggestions for examples or other reading?

Answer (score 0):

I found a project that I think will work.  If anybody else is interested, look into wbem-sharp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how active wbem-sharp currently is...

As an alternatve, you could use the [SFCC client](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sblim/index.php?title=Sfcc), and integrate its C-Language client API into C#. SFCC is well-maintained and supports the current CIM/WBEM standards.